# Bind click events on loaded ajax contents

Tags: javascript, ajax, function-binding

I'm trying to load contents through ajax and then perform some click events on those contents.

So basically I want to first load the contents(Buttons in this case) and then apply some click events on them .

and hence I'm using **callbacks** for the purpose to load the contents first and then apply click events , but here I've a problem that the content is loaded after the callback function, and I don't want this, I want to load the content first then execute callback function, how to solve this problem?

To achieve this till now I've the following code.

I've following code in `food.php`:

```
<button onclick="findWeek(fun)">week</button>    // fun is callback function passed to findWeek()
```

`// findWeek` function    ------ AJAX request to load buttons    ------:

```
function findWeek(fun)      
             {              
                var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET" ,"start.php",true);
                xhr.send(null);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if( (xhr.readyState == '4') && ( xhr.status == '200') ){

                        document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    }

                };


                fun();
            }
```

`// fun` function, is a **callback** function, and I'm assuming that this will come in action when the `findWeek()` function load the contents,meaning that it will load the required buttons from the page `start.php` inserting those buttons to the following div which is inside `food.php`.

```
<div id = 'stats'>
</div>
```

And after that I want to be able to click those loaded  buttons then which are supposed to be there in the above `div`.

That's why I've `fun()` function something like following.

**Note:** I've defined class `.dayBtns` for the loaded buttons.

```
function fun(){

    function myfunction(){
        alert('just clicked the button');
    }
    var dayBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('dayBtns');
    alert('contents should be loaded');
    for(var i = 0; i < dayBtns.length; i++){
        console.log(dayBtns[i]);
        btns[i].addEventListener('click', myfunction);
        }

}
```

The problem is the content is loading after the `fun()` function execution, how to restrict `fun()` function not to execute until the data is not loaded ?

Please help , thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Just place `fun()` into onreadystatechange like so -

```
function findWeek(fun) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "start.php", true);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ((xhr.readyState == '4') && (xhr.status == '200')) {

            document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            fun();
        }

    };


}
```

The innerHTML is set **after** the function fun is called so there are no elements in the DOM at that point.

You also have a typo on the code here:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < dayBtns.length; i++){
    console.log(dayBtns[i]);
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', myfunction);
 }
```

Should be:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < dayBtns.length; i++){
    console.log(dayBtns[i]);
    dayBtns[i].addEventListener('click', myfunction);
 }
```

Notice **dayBtns** vs **btns**

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: after those changes also,Still the `fun()` is called first, and the content  is loaded lately

Comment: that typo was  because I made a lot of changes, that wasn't  there before.